# How to escape html from reddit api response

Tags: java, android, json, reddit

I'm using the reddit API to build an android reddit client. I send a GET to https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/top/.json and get back the top posts, each with a selftext_html string. I then try to load the selftext_html onto an android WebView using `webView.loadData(selftext_html, "text/html", null)`.

However, the html string always displays as plaintext. The online reddit repo says this about selftext_html:

```
"NOTE: The HTML string will be escaped. You must unescape to get the raw HTML. Null if not present."
```

I tried unescaping the string using `Html.escapeHtml()` and several other methods, but it still displays as plaintext. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It says to unescape it.  Not to escape it.  escapeHtml goes in the wrong direction.

Comment: Wow, I completely misread that. Thank you!